# TCP server received delayed message from client

Tags: c#, tcp

I have an TCP Listener as a TCP server in C# app. Beside TCP server, there are also MQTT and Kafka modules. This is my code:

- Starting TCP listener, listen if a client connected to server

```cs
public async void Run()
{
    try
    {
        if (!IsRunning)
        {
            IsRunning = true;

            clientTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            clientListener = new TcpListener(Ip, ServerPort);
            clientListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    TcpClient RemoteClient = await clientListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                    IPEndPoint clientIP = RemoteClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;

                    _ = InitializePmsClient(RemoteClient);
                }
                catch (Exception _ex)
                {
                    Logger.Error(_ex)
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Manually close all connected clients
            for (int i = clientCollection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = clientCollection[i].TcpClient;
                IPEndPoint clientIP = tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
                tcpClient.Close();
                clientCollection[i].Connected = false;
                Logger.Info("Disconnected to client")
            }

            // Wait for all of the clients to finish closing
            await Task.WhenAll(clientTasks);
            clientTasks.Clear();
            clientTokenSource.Dispose();
            clientCollection.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            clientTokenSource.Cancel();
            clientListener.Stop();
            IsRunning = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex)
    }
}
```

- Init TCP client

```
private PmsClient InitializePmsClient(TcpClient remoteClient)
{
    PmsClient client = new PmsClient(Logger)
    {
        TcpClient = remoteClient
    };
    client.TcpClient.NoDelay = true;
    client.Connected = true;
    client.KeepAlivePeriod = KeepAlivePeriod;

    client.ProcessDataTask = ProcessClientAsync(client, clientTokenSource.Token); // Process when received message
    client.SendDataTask = TaskSendMessage(client); // Dequeue message from queue to client
    client.SendKeepAlive(); // Send keep alive message periodically

    clientCollection.Add(client);
    Logger.Info("Client connected")

    return client;
}
```

- Process when received message from client

```
private async Task ProcessClientAsync(PmsClient client, CancellationToken token)
{
    int max_read_len = 4096;
    try
    {
        // Begin reading from the client's data stream
        using (NetworkStream stream = client.TcpClient.GetStream())
        {
            int read = 1;
            while (read > 0)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[client.TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, max_read_len, token);
                client.ProcessData(buffer, read); // Format data from buffer
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex)
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            client.TcpClient.Close();
            clientTasks.Remove(client.ProcessDataTask);
            clientTasks.Remove(client.SendDataTask);
            clientCollection.Remove(client);
            Logger.Info("Client disconnected")
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Error(exception)
        }
    }
}
```

- More detail when process incoming data

```
public void ProcessData(byte[] data, int read)
{
    PmsMessage Message = new PmsMessage();
    Booking booking;
    try
    {
        if (read > 0)
        {   
            Received.AddRange(data.Take(read));
            Logger.Info("Received data", Received) // <---------------------- Logging data when received data from client

            // Read from buffer until message receive all message
            bool CompleteMessage = Message.IsCompleteMessage(ref Received, out result);
            while (CompleteMessage)
            {
                // Trigger event handle message received logic
                OnMessageTrigger(new MessageEventArgs(result));
                CompleteMessage = Message.IsCompleteMessage(ref Received, out result);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex)
    }
}
```

My problem is, sometimes, messages from TCP client got delayed when came server (in log above). Delay time between several minutes to 2 hours. When the time messages are no longer delayed, all messages in delay time come immediately.

I've checked where delay comes from by using Wireshark

```
TCP Client ---> Wireshark ---> TCP Server
```

- Message came Wireshark at the same time client sent message. Thus, I think problem come from TCP Server. I've tested in local but can reproduce error. Anyone has any idea about this error?

### UPDATE

- According to @JonasH in comment, I've updated code to run TCP server in background by command

```
tcpServer = new TcpServer();
_ = Task.Run(tcpServer.Run)
```

But it seem not working. Anyone have idea?

Comment: Is the server an UI app? just to make sure there is no issue with synchronization to the UI thread? If you break your program when a message has gotten delayed, is any thread stuck at some unexpected place? I'm no network expert, but the posted code looks reasonable to me. I can't spot any of the usual TCP pitfalls.

Comment: @JonasH,firstly, it's an UI app. Then I have another service app to start it to run in background (`System.ServiceProcess.BaseService`). Beside, the app has log when any connection connected/disconnected or when app restart too. And messages sent from client still come to server with exactly content, it just take too long to come to server

Comment: You probably want to ensure `Run()` is not called from the UI thread. For network code you probably want to run any receiving code in the background, and only synchronize to the UI thread when needed. Otherwise you risk the network code blocking the UI or vice versa.

Comment: @JonasH, In my UI thread, function was called `server.Run()` but when function declared, it contains `async` key word, so I think it already run in backgroud

Comment: async only rewrites the method to a state machine, it does not make anything run on a background thread. You need to use `Task.Run()`, or in some cases , `await myTask.ConfigureAwait(false)` to move execution to a background thread.

Comment: @JonasH, that makes sense, in the machine which installed my application, it has crash errors with `dwm.exe`. I think that why errors only occur on that machine. I've updated my app, but due to unable to re-produce error on other machine, I'm not sure this update can fix above error. But thanks for you help

Comment: @JonasH Hi, I've moved tcpServer into background thread (updated on post), but it does not worked only on server production (in local or test environment everything works fine). On server production, the delay event even occurs more frequently with small time, < 60 second. But sometimes, the delay occur very long (about 10 minutes ~ 2 hours). I think this can be server enviroment, but don't know where to start. Do you have any suggestion?